# Oracle - Concatenate Strings as column name

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to concatenate strings that are used as column names

I want to do something like:

```
Select someData as "ONE" || :someVariable) from sometable;
```

where someVariable is a bind variable, which does not work inside double quotes.
(The column should have the name `"ONE2018"` if `someVariable = 2018`.)

I tried it with single quotes and with the concat function. It doesn't work.
Is there some way to accomplish this?

EDIT:
With inspiration from littlefoots answer I tried

```
declare
  customVariable number(4);
  rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open rc for 'select 1 as bla' || :customVariable || ' from dual';
  dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
 end;
/
```

which does have the output

```
   BLA2018
----------
         1
```

I don't know how to put that into a PreparedStatement, but if used on it's own it works and might help someone else

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to change column names.

Answer (score 2):

An example based on Scott's `EMP` table which contains columns whose names begins with an `E`: `ENAME` and `EMPNO`.

You'd pass `NAME` or `MPNO` and get the result.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_one (par_column_name in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5    l_str varchar2(200);
  6  begin
  7    l_str := 'select e' || par_column_name || ' from emp where rownum < 3';
  8    open l_rc for l_str;
  9    return l_rc;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_one('mpno') from dual;

F_ONE('MPNO')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO
----------
      7369
      7499


SQL> select f_one('name') from dual;

F_ONE('NAME')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME
----------
SMITH
ALLEN


SQL>
```